# How to get corresponding attributes and values of datatable while server side processing in java

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

How to get current order column name,search key, and how to parse all datatable info to usable format.

This my code snipet:
 index.html

```
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>FullName</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>FullName</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        </table>

</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            processing: true,
            serverSide : true,
            deferRender: true,
            order:  [[0, 'asc']],
            paging : true,

            "ajax": {
                url:"data-source",
                type:"POST",
                //type : "application/json",
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "firstName" },
                { "data": "lastName" },
                { "data": "fullName" },
                { "data" : function(o){
                    //console.log(o);
                    return "email";
                }
                }
            ]
        } );
    } );
} );

</script>
```

server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/data-source",method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET},produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Object simpleJson1(HttpServletRequest r,@RequestBody String s) throws Employee1DaoException{
    System.out.println("simpleJson1");
    System.out.println(s);
    HashMap<String, String> returnHash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Enumeration<String> obj = r.getParameterNames();
    int cnt=0;
    List<Employee1> le=new ArrayList<>();

    while (obj.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String paramName = obj.nextElement();
        String paramValue = r.getParameter(paramName);
        returnHash.put(paramName, paramValue);
    }
    Object o=r.getParameterMap();

    System.out.println("o="+o);
    System.out.println(returnHash);
    System.out.println(r.getParameterValues("order"));

    int ppView=Integer.parseInt(returnHash.get("length"));
    int pageIndex=Integer.parseInt(returnHash.get("start"));
    int draw=Integer.parseInt(returnHash.get("draw"));
    String searchKey=returnHash.get("search[value]");


    System.out.println(ppView+"="+pageIndex+"="+searchKey);
    String where="";
    System.out.println(searchKey);
    if(searchKey!=null && !searchKey.isEmpty() && !searchKey.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
        where=" WHERE Id LIKE '%"+searchKey+"%' OR FirstName LIKE '%"+searchKey+"%' OR LastName LIKE '%"
               +searchKey+"%'  OR FullName LIKE '%"+searchKey+"%' OR Email LIKE '%"+searchKey+"%'";
        draw=0;
    }
    where+=" limit "+(pageIndex)+","+ppView;
    System.out.println(where);
    cnt=employee1Dao.findAll().size();
    le=employee1Dao.findByQuery(where);
    System.out.println(le);
    Map<String, Object> m1=new HashMap<>();

    m1.put("draw", draw);
    m1.put("recordsTotal", 50);
    m1.put("recordsFiltered", 50);
    m1.put("data", le);

    return m1;
}
```

This is what am getting from datatable:

```
{columns[2][search][regex]=false, columns[2][searchable]=true, columns[0][search][value]=, columns[1][orderable]=true, columns[2][name]=, columns[3][name]=, search[value]=, columns[1][data]=firstName, columns[3][data]=fullName, columns[1][searchable]=true, draw=1, columns[0][data]=id, columns[4][search][value]=, columns[4][data]=function, length=10, columns[0][name]=, columns[0][search][regex]=false, columns[2][data]=lastName, columns[1][search][value]=, columns[4][name]=, columns[0][orderable]=true, columns[3][search][value]=, columns[1][name]=, columns[3][searchable]=true, columns[2][search][value]=, order[0][column]=0, columns[1][search][regex]=false, order[0][dir]=asc, start=0, columns[4][searchable]=true, columns[0][searchable]=true, columns[2][orderable]=true, search[regex]=false, columns[4][search][regex]=false, columns[3][orderable]=true, columns[4][orderable]=true, columns[3][search][regex]=false}
```

sample data from server to client datatable:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsFiltered":50,"data":[{"id":1,"firstName":"Dana","lastName":"Mangum","fullName":"Patrick Bray","email":"email@email"},{"id":2,"firstName":"Terry","lastName":"Connolly","fullName":"Dorothy Rose","email":"email@email"},{"id":3,"firstName":"Richard","lastName":"Fisher","fullName":"Anna Schwartz","email":"email@email"},{"id":4,"firstName":"Allen","lastName":"Lowry","fullName":"Vanessa Fuller","email":"email@email"},{"id":5,"firstName":"Marcia","lastName":"Connor","fullName":"Jane Love","email":"email@email"},{"id":6,"firstName":"Heidi","lastName":"Caldwell","fullName":"Katie Hardy","email":"email@email"},{"id":7,"firstName":"Danny","lastName":"Middleton","fullName":"Audrey Cowan","email":"email@email"},{"id":8,"firstName":"Phyllis","lastName":"Arnold","fullName":"Vivian Caldwell","email":"email@email"},{"id":9,"firstName":"Teresa","lastName":"Pickett","fullName":"Cheryl Sawyer","email":"email@email"},{"id":10,"firstName":"Jennifer","lastName":"Goldman","fullName":"Jeff Watkins","email":"email@email"}],"recordsTotal":50}
```

Comment: Have you seen [Server-side processing with Spring MVC](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29550/server-side-processing-with-spring-mvc)?